# QtWebEngineView error at show()

Tags: qt, opengl, webview, qtwebengine

I have recently started using QWebEngineView class from qt5.7 and i am getting these errors every time i show my webview for the first time:

> QSGContext::initialize: depth buffer support missing, expect rendering errors
>   QSGContext::initialize: stencil buffer support missing, expect rendering errors.
>   QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
>   QOpenGLFramebufferObject: Framebuffer incomplete attachment.
>   [opengl\qopenglframebufferobject.cpp line 736] OpenGL Error: 1280`

I build it like this:

```
QWebEngineView* webview = new QWebEngineView(&parentWidget);
webview->setGeometry(QRect(0,0,Constants::NOTIFICATION_WIDTH, Constants::NOTIFICATION_HEIGHT));
```

And I show it like this:

```
webview->setHtml(html, baseurl);
QObject::connect(webview, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &parentWidget, SLOT(show()));
```

The webview appears to load the html correctly but once i display it, the html appears after a delay. I think this delay happens due to the OpenGL errors i mentioned earlier because the second time i show() the webview it appears instantly, without any errors.

I am working on a Citrix Windows 8 machine and i have a Citrix display driver.

How can i fix these errors, or how can i make it the webview display instantly the first time i show() it?

Comment: I think your code is ok. The trouble either with OpenGL or Qt installation. Did you download Qt from Qt site or compile yourself?

Comment: I have installed it from qt site with qt installer

Comment: I have tested something and I think that those errors may not be the cause of my delayed html display. So, my question now is: Does QWebEngineView emit a signal when it finishes rendering? Because i may connect the show() after this signal is emitted.

Comment: Well, you have loadFinished or renderProcessTerminated, try and use what is best in your case